# context-managed resource on module level

Tags: python, fastapi

I am looking for a pattern where I have multiple functions that need access to a resource that is context-managed.

In particular, I am using `fastAPI` and want to re-use `aiopg` (async `psycopg2`) connections.

This is the basic layout:

```py
@app.get("/hello")
def hello():
    async with aiopg.connect(...) as conn:
        async with conn.cursor(...):
            return cursor.execute(...)
```

Now I want to avoid a connection per route. I could think of an object outside, and in the route I either access the `conn` property or await creation (and store back) and then just use the `with` on the `cursor()` method.

```py
class Pg():
    async def conn(self):
        if not self._conn:
            self._conn = await aiopg.connect(...)
        return self._conn

myPg = Pg()

@app.get("/hello")
def hello():
    conn = await myPg.conn()
    async with conn.cursor(...):
        return cursor.execute(...)
```

However, I then would lose the ability to automatically close the connection.

I think that I miss something really obvious here and hope that someone could guide me how to implement this properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aiopg provides a [`Pool` class](https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core.html#pool) that can manage connections.

just create a pool instance at the module level:

```py
pool = await aiopg.create_pool('<your connection string>')
```

Then you can use the [`Pool.acquire`](https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core.html#aiopg.Pool.acquire) context-manager to get a connection:

```py
async with pool.acquire() as conn:
    ...
```

If connections already exist in the pool, they will be re-used.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the `Pool` hint, this may be a solution. But assuming that a pool would need to be `close()`d or the like, this would bear the same sort of problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user4344 whats does mean "automatically close the connection"? close it after a period of activity? after the end of a particular process? anyway Pool will indeed probably not handle this for you. But I don't think it is a problem to let the connections live for the whole application runtime, they will be closed when the application quits (with explicit `pool.close()` or, I guess, by the `pool.__del__` invocation when the pool is destroyed)

Comment: I mean: If I was able to open the connection or the connection pool with a context manager, then it would be closed automatically, like in my first example where the connection is closed. But with what I was posting in the example, there is no "block" that will be left call the context manager `__leave__()` method. But as you say: it most probably won't be a problem to not explicitely `close()` the connection or the pool. I'll go with your suggestion to use the pool!